# Django Template not rendering mission information

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to render some information in the template but it isn't showing on even though I think I implemented it right.

I'm working on my consultant dashboard (consultant is a user type)

My template :

```
 <div class="form-group">
                  {% csrf_token %}
                <label>Mission </label>
                <select class="form-control" name="mission" id="mission">
                    {% for mission in mission %}
                      <option value="{{ mission.id }}">{{ mission.mission_name }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
              </div>
```

models.py:

```
class Mission(models.Model):
    id=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    mission_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    client_id=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=models.CASCADE,default=1)
    consultant_id=models.ForeignKey(Consultant,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    objects=models.Manager()
```

My view:

```
def staff_take_attendance(request):
    mission=Mission.objects.filter(consultant_id=request.user.id)


    return render(request,"staff_template/staff_take_attendance.html",{"mission":mission})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution

I had a problem in my view, I should get the user id before filtering...

```
def staff_take_attendance(request):
consultant=Consultant.objects.get(admin=request.user.id)
mission=Mission.objects.filter(consultant_id=consultant.id)

return render(request,"staff_template/staff_take_attendance.html",{"mission":mission,})
```